# Time to execute Stored Procedure in java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, time

I have the next code:

```
public void executeVoid_SP(Connection con, String spName) throws EtiGottaException {
    System.out.println(spName);

    try {
        //cs = con.prepareCall("{ call " + spName + "}");
        cs = con.prepareCall("exec dbo." + spName);
        cs.execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new EtiGottaException("SqlStoredProcedure: " + e.getMessage());

    }

}
```

The problem is when call the method execute, the app tarry to execute the method but if I execute the stored procedure in SQL, this procedure is executing in seconds. Anyone know, what happend?

Comment: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) Using `EXEC` I guess it is TSQL

Comment: I try to execute with exec and with call. But I have the same problem